# VS Code Snippets: How to replace underscore with spaces and capitalize words

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I can replace underscores with spaces from the `$1` like this `${1/[_]/ /g}`

And the capitalization is done with `${1/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/}`

But how to combine both to get a result like this:

`model_name` --> `Model Name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`"${1/([^_]*)(_?)/${1:/capitalize}${2:+ }/g}"`

That will capture everything before an underscore in group 1 and capitalize that group.

The underscore, if any, will be in capture group 2.  `${2:+ }` is a conditional: if there is a capture group 2, add a space.

Note the global `g` at the end is necessary to repeatedly match each of these groups along the input.

It will work with any length input from:

```
model
model_name
model_name_more_stuff    // etc.
```